# Unable to install Windows Web Services API for Remote Debugging with VS2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2012, wwsapi

I'm trying to remote debug using visual studio 2012 and windows server 2008 not R2.  I recieve the following error when setting up the remote debugger.

Has anyone else been able to install 2012 remote debugger on Windows server 2008 that is not R2?

This is the full error message after I hit configure remote debugging.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [VS 2012 system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility) remote debugging is not supported on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Looking at the information here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30674 -- It notes WS2008 SP2 x86 and x64 are supported. Bad documentation? Same issue for me though @MichaelGrassman

Comment: Thanks I'll have to try this update out.  I wasn't using the update 1 version before.

Comment: Just tried this out and unfortunately it doesn't update the Windows Web Services API which is still required is still only supported with Server 2008 R2 not just 2008.

Answer (score 3):

At [this MS forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/11bd5a3a-263d-49ec-b50e-45cb0ffa4c6f) Brad Sullivan the Program Manager for Visual Studio Debugger has posted the following:

> There is a known issue in the installer for Remote Tools for Visual
>   Studio 2012 that is breaking remote debugging on Windows Server 2008. 
>   While we work on this issue, you can use the following work-around:
>
> 1)   If not already, please install “Platform Update for Windows
>   Server 2008 (KB971644)” from Window Update. It will
>   install KB971512, KB971513, and KB960362 in “Control Panel -> Programs
>   and Features -> Installed Updates”.
>
> 2)   Install Windows Live Essentials from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=255474
>
> Following these instructions should prevent you from seeing the error
>   regarding Windows Web Services API.

As odd as it sounds, I can confirm this to have fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Link for Platform Update for Windows Server 2008 is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644 (don't have enough rep to post three links at once)