# How to install Windows Web Services API (WWSAPI) in a Server w/o Internet Access

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging, dmz, wwsapi

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2012 Remote Debugger in a Server with Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 x64 located in a DMZ, in a Development Environment. This server doesn't access to the Internet directly but through a Firewall. So, I downloaded the Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 from my workstation, and copy it to the Server, install it and everything is ok.

Well, when I started the Remote Debugger Configuration Wizard, and it try to install the Windows Web Service API, it fails and shows the next message:

> ### Failed to complete the Visual Studio Remote Debugger Configuration Wizard
>
> The debugger was unable to install Windows Web Services API. 
>   Downloading the update installer failed. Please ensure that your
>   computer is able to access the internet.
>
> Download URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwklink/?LinkId=215754
>   Internal code: 0x800c0005
>
> To close the wizard, click Finish.

So, because I'm a good boy, I press Finish to close the wizard. But before I go to the Download URL provided by the wizard, and has no success because it drive me to the Microsoft.com Search (http://search.microsoft.com/en-US/search.aspx).

But, I'm a man! I will not cry, and keep googling (searching?) but this time I was searching for WWSAPI Redistributable, but has no success at the time, then I search for a similar situation to mine here, and this is what I got [Unable to install Windows Web Services API for Remote Debugging with VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945430/unable-to-install-windows-web-services-api-for-remote-debugging-with-vs2012), but doesn't has a solution, so I decided to ask at StackOverflow because, I'm almost desperate to find a solution for this. So, I hope you can help me to find a Solution to my situation. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please let us know what's your server OS version?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 x64

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to workaround described here, it solves this exact problem:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763521/cannot-run-visual-studio-2012-remote-debugger-on-windows-server-2008-non-r2

> Install Windows Live Essentials from the following link.
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=255474
>
> One of the installed dependencies is the required Web Services API.

Also, please, sign in and vote for the bug solution, to give regard **JustinPealing** who worried first to open the bug, and who found this workaround